# Don't show Object Tag, only its attributes with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

If I have 3 objects A, B and C. Where A has B which has C, I don't want to show:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c/>
  </b>
</a>
```

I want to show:

```
<a>
  <c/>
</a>
```

Is there any way to do it with JAXB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`XmlAdapter<C, B>`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) to marshal the contained `C` instead of `B`